# How can i use google fonts in sharepoint online?

Tags: branding, style, style.css

Has anyone used google fonts in sharepoint online?
Will it work at all or is it worth the effort?
Any recommendation would be grateful.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where exactly you want to use google fonts in SharePoint Online?

Comment: Thanks Ganesh i have a certain requirement.Thats why

Comment: Yes, I got that. But where exactly are you trying to use google fonts? Are you trying to customize master page? Or are you trying to use it in SPFx web part styles? Or anywhere else on SharePoint pages? Classic or modern?

Comment: Its a sharepoint site in a classic mode and yes in a webpart header title to be more specific and the fonts of the text in the webpart.
Hope it make sense